# Changing TextView content in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have a fragment, where you actually have 3 pages, you can swipe with. 
On each page you have a default String like this "Hello World from section: %1$d" which is saved in strings. xml "

And the fragment java class method looks like this:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_generaldiscription, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        textView.setText("test"); // testing purposes
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My question is: I don't want every page  to have the same Text. Section 1 has "Hello world from section: 1" , section 2 has "Hello world from section: 2"

I want that section 1 has a different string like "hello, this is section 1 of your fragment." How can I adress the different sections in my fragment in order to show different strings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need a variable to show diffenent strings.That's why the strings.xml doesn't work.

---

Here is my solution

Step1:

custom a constructor which contains a String object to descripbe the textview

Step2:

Init three fragments objects with different strings in your FragmentAdapter class

Step3:
Test it whther it can work

Well.The code is a little tedious,It's not convinent for me to write here.Just try, you can get it :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a pain in the ass to deal with.
I like to use [Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) instead. To add a page you just need:`adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 1");` , and customisations are done within fragment class

Answer (score 1):

I think on every page u got "Hello world from section: 1" and if u add another text on section 2 page it overlaps the both the text into one another.
I got that problem, then i use android:background="#ffffff" in layout so section 1 text becomes white due to background colour, if u want another colour or image set in background.
and then section 2 will show only "Hello world from section: 2" set it through xml.
This is not perfect solution but it works for me.